# Keynote 8: change dropdown colors

Tags: applications, keynote, color

I want to change the colors that appear in the dropdown here:

[image: Color choices]

If I open the Colors window and select another color, nothing changes. The steps outlined for older versions of Keynote don't work.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that portion of the color selector is encoded in the theme, which unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to edit just yet. However, you can add custom colors to the color picker. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Yeah, @JMY1000, that is exactly what I've done so far. It doesn't help with that drop down, though. Perhaps I need to edit the theme...

Comment: I tried editing the colors when editing the master slide and exporting as a theme, but it didn't work. Unfortunately I can't edit the files directly either since they're binaries and there's no good info on what to edit that I'm aware of, and old versions that use XML don't have the same swatches AFAIK.